# Matlab image file convert from *.PPM into *.PGM?

Tags: image, matlab

I have dataset of training images in .ppm format.

But when I want to extract the feature using [SIFT descriptor from Lowe](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/), I have an problem.

Because my training images dataset is in *.PPM format, but to use SIFT function from lowe, the images required is in *.PGM format.

Everytime I give my *.PPM image file, I always get this error

```
          Error using  ' 
          Transpose on ND array is not defined.

          Error in sift (line 38)
          fwrite(f, image', 'uint8');
```

I know that I can convert my *.PPM image inti *.PGM by using

```
           imwrite(image,'test.pgm')
```

But it means, that I'll make new file with *.PGM format, And I dont need it..

Any idea??

Comment: it seems like the issue is not the file format but rather color vs gray-scale images issue: SIFT is operating on gray scale images and your input images seems to be color images.

Comment: PGM and PPM are both simple image formats, collectively called PNM files (Portable aNy Map).  PGM is grayscale (Portable Gray Map), and PPM is color (Portable Pixel Map).  Convert your RGB data loaded from your PPM file to grayscale, and you'll be fine.